# Extracting image pixel values in google appengine

Tags: java, google-app-engine

I am working on google appengine to create a tool for comparing image similarity.
I need to extract the pixel values of each image to perform this.
Unfortunately appengine does not support the java image libs.So I am unable to proceed.

Is there any appengine safe image library in java capable of extracting image data?
I saw some techniques in python but dont want to switch to python if I can do it in java somehow...

Comment: I haven't used AppEngine but it claims to support Java 6. So you should therefore be able to use BufferedImage.getRGB() to get a pixel value?

Comment: Google AppEngine does not support all the libraries in Java 6. They haven't supported those libraries which they believe would not be used in server side. Buffered image is defined in java.awt.image lib which is not supported in appengine.

Comment: @mikera BufferedImage is a restricted class (ie, not supported)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GAEJ has its own [graphic library](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/java/images/) with fairly limited features and `java.awt.image.BufferedImage` is a restricted class (ie, `java.awt.Image` is not supported and still not present in the [Jre Class White List](http://code.google.com/intl/it-IT/appengine/docs/java/jrewhitelist.html) ).

There's an open issue [here](http://code.google.com/p/googleappengine/issues/detail?id=1423), that you might want to star.

**EDIT:**
Somebody has patched [pngj](https://github.com/jakeri/pngj-for-Google-App-Engine) to work with InputStream.(You could use it to read a PNG pixel by pixel)

Comment: thanks for the reply.. am going to try out the pngj lib mentioned. Will post back if I find a solution

Answer (score 1):

The new version of [pngj](http://code.google.com/p/pngj/) now an alternative pngj-sandbox.jar that only references whitelisted classes, it should run in google-app-engine.

Answer (score 0):

can https://github.com/witwall/appengine-awt help to you? i believe it willbe enough to add theis lib as dependency to the project to make BufferedImage working (but havent' tried this yet)